# pycharm recnoizes import yet still ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package django project on make migrations

Tags: python, django, import, pycharm

look at this photograph... (everytime I do it makes me laugh.... lol I had to what a terrible band..anyway)[image: Nonsense]

I am trying to import the views.py file from my venue directory into the urls.py file in the suitsandtables directory which is on the same level as my venue directory.

Each one of these directories has a `__init__.py` file which is empty. Pycharm is all happy yet I still get the `ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package` error. Which is starting to drive me insane.

Can we fix this nonsense? Gracious

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Attempted relative import in non-package" even with \_\_init\_\_.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/how-to-fix-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py)

Comment: Try `from venue.views import something`

Comment: yep that works. Pycharm doesn't like it but it works thanks

Comment: Mark the right directory as *Sources root*

Answer (score 6):

Use `from venue.views import something`

Instead of `from ..venus import views`